# Python In Visual Studio Code and Modules not importing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been using visual studio code for most programming and learning to do it. but when coming to the point when i try to test out importing modules such as Random for random number Generation

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXmNa.jpg)
A picture containing all the error code i got and the few lines i had written in python

Using stackOverflow and google to try and find someone who had a similar issue resolved in no found questions or answers which were related exactly

Comment: Did you named the file containing your code random.py? if so I think you can solve your problem by changing the name of the file to something else. Python is actually confusing your file with the random module.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text that you can copy and paste into your post. That's part of the advice from here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example